# How to write magento 1.x config.xml to magento 2.0 config.xml?

Tags: magento2

i Had the magento 1.x config.xml file,i need that write into magento 2.0 structure.
For ex:

2.0.0

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <FacebookComments>
                <file>socialshare/FacebookComments.xml</file>
            </FacebookComments>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <facebookcomments translate="title" module="facebookcomments">
                                        <title>Social Share - Facebook Comments</title>
                                    </facebookcomments>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>      
</adminhtml>

<global>
    <resources>
        <FacebookComments_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>SocialShare_FacebookComments</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </FacebookComments_setup>
        <FacebookComments_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </FacebookComments_write>
        <FacebookComments_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </FacebookComments_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <FacebookComments>
            <class>SocialShare_FacebookComments_Block</class>
        </FacebookComments>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <facebookcomments>
            <class>SocialShare_FacebookComments_Helper</class>
        </facebookcomments>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <facebookcomments>
            <class>SocialShare_FacebookComments_Model</class>
        </facebookcomments>
    </models>
</global>

<default>
    <facebookcomments>
        <conf>
            <enabled>0</enabled>
            <posts>5</posts>
            <width>500</width>
            <colorscheme>light</colorscheme>
        </conf>
    </facebookcomments>
</default>
```

this above config.xml is magento 1.x,this file convert into magento 2.0 structure.

Answer (score 1):

in magneto2 no need to mention `block`, `helper`, `resources`, `table name`, etc. in `config` file

and also it split many `xml` file

ex :- `routes.xml`
`crontab.xml`

cross check catalog module which will help you

Comment: can u plz give me any referenced links for this?

Comment: AFAIK, Magento documentation does not talk about mapping a Magento 1 configuration to Magento 2 but for a start, you can see the [two deployment configuration files](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-php.html) and [module configuration files](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 there are many separations of config.xml file. For that you have to refer documentation.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/bk-architecture.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html